# Shortcode displays only default attribute values

Tags: shortcode, customization

For some reasons every shortcode, that I try to add to functions.php, displays only default attribute value and ignores what I specify in a post. E.g.:

```
function my_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => '18',
        ), $atts )
    );
    return $id;
}
add_shortcode( 'sc', 'my_shortcode' );
```

So I use shortcode `[sc id="81"]` and expect echoing `81` but I get `18`. BTW I use child theme, and latest version of wordpress. I'm really stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you make sure it's not a cache issue? Try changing 18 to something else.

Comment: avoid using `extract` here as it may result in broken-ness and it can overwrite globals making this a security issue too

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your exact code, putting the PHP code you pasted above in my theme's `functions.php` file, and inserting the shortcode as you typed `[sc id="81"]` in to a page in my site, publishing the page, and it correctly outputted a value of `81` on my published page.

So something in your theme or a plugin must be conflicting with it.

Try changing to one of the default WordPress themes and testing it again, and/or disabling your plugins.

I suspect it could be a conflict because the parameter is named '`id`' - so you could also try using a different parameter name (eg. '`myid`').